# How can i split string to get contact number?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get contact number from string but failed.

**My code:**

```
url="https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/2121711837_zpid/47.285925,-122.4099 
25,47.224756,-122.549143_rect/12_zm/1_fr//"

 browser = webdriver.Firefox() 
 browser.get(url)
 soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')

try:
   contact_info= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='ds-listing-a 
   gent-info']")
   contact_info = contact_info.text.strip()
   print("Contact number : " + contact_info)
except:
    try:
      contact_info= 
      browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='property-info contact- 
      phone']")
      contact_info = contact_info.text.strip()
      print("Contact number : " + contact_info)
    except:
      contact_info= 
      browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='property-info contact- 
      phone']")
      contact_info = contact_info.text.strip()
      print("Contact number : " + contact_info)
```

**Output from my code**

Contact number : Tyler Edwards

5 / 5 5 reviews

Call: (253) 381-0981

**Expected Result**

Contact number : (253) 381-0981

Can anyone find best possible solution. Thanks

Comment: Is the variable `contact_info` as `Tyler Edwards

5 / 5 5 reviews

Call: (253) 381-0981`?

Comment: `try-except` are doing the same thing? Why do you need them then?

Comment: @pistol2myhead Yes, contact_info is a variable which store string.

Comment: @Austin i need them because Zillow has different classes name.

Comment: everything after the first except is duplicate so you try to do something then if that doesnt work you are doing exactly the same thing...the last try except there is doing nothing really....you just want contact_info to return the phone number right?

Comment: Note that zillow has an API _and_ their FAQ (https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/faq.htm) basically says use it; using a crawler violates our ToS

Comment: well where is the name and reviews coming from are they all getting stored in that contact_info variable?

Comment: @Brent I want contact number from my output. How can i split output string to get only contact number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a find so you could do something like create a new variable off your contact info

```
contact_info = "whatever your setting contact info to"
```

then find the ( that starts the phone number

```
contact = contact_info[contact_info.find("("):]


print("Contact number:" + contact)
```

that should work for a simple way to do it without using regex but just like the regex this will only work if its that format (area code) phone number

Comment: Thanks! finally i get my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to substring the text you are returning in `contact_info`

```
contact_info  = '''
Contact number : Tyler Edwards

5 / 5 5 reviews

Call: (253) 381-0981'''

start = contact_info.find('Call: ')+6 # Find where Call starts and add 6 to account for the text

contact_info = contact_info[start:]
```

Output

```
'(253) 381-0981'
```

Answer (score 0):

If in you code, `contact_info = "Tyler Edwards 5 / 5 5 reviews Call: (253) 381-0981"`, then you can try regex to find the matching numbers in the exact format with this :

```
import re
phn_no = re.findall(r'\d{,3}\D{,2}\d{,3}-\d{,4}', contact_info)
# Output : phn_no = ['253) 381-0981']
```

Or, if the string always contain `'Call'` and after that the phone number at last, then try this :

```
phn_no = ci[ci.lower().rfind('call')+5:]
# Output : phn_no = ' (253) 381-0981'
```

Note: The regex part will not work for other formats of phone numbers like `+7 123 41 86 789`

Answer (score 0):

You can grab from one of the hidden input elements after using a wait condition

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/2121711837_zpid/47.263111,-122.466574,47.247644,-122.492452_rect/14_zm/1_fr/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
phone =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[name=zmailRecipientPhone]'))).get_attribute('value')
print(phone)
```